# I want to sell a simple calculator. What is the simplest way to implement registration keys?

Tags: licensing, software

I want to sell a simple calculator that will help a certain industry. This calculator would be installed on the computer (as opposed to a web service). How is a registration key mechanism implemented?

Comment: First off, please ask only one question per question.  I count at least three in there.  Next, resource requests (tutorials) are off topic as is the "what is the best language for XYZ" type question.  Could you please check the  [help/on-topic] and consider narrowing your question to the appropriate topics for the site?

Comment: You want a web registration system for a simple calculator. So does that mean that I need to be online to use your simple calculator? Seriously?

Comment: No, I want to make it so that you don't have to be online. Like an .exe file on their computer. I do want them to need some sort of key though, so they don't install it on other computers or upload the program somewhere.

Comment: @WorldEngineer Hmm... this seems legitimate, doesn't it?

Comment: @SouthpawHare Still a tad broad but I'll open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *simplest* way to implement registration keys is to trust your users.  (Or, "don't use keys.")  As long as your sales contract is clear enough and written properly, you can use the courts to collect against the odd successful scofflaw.

Going upwards from that in complexity and security, you have:

1. Sell your calculator exclusively via an online store, a'la Windows, Android, or iPhone.
2. Generate a "registration key" based on a relatively short private key and some incremental number.  Require this key to be manually entered at install time, and present in the Windows Registry (or similar system-level repository) at run-time.
3. Have your installer "dial home" via HTTP to your registration server, sending a hash of information about the system it's installed upon as well as the installation sale number.  Return a private-key-signed registration code, as #2 above.
4. Have your application itself "dial home" on a regular basis for updates, and check the registration silently at the same time.  If you notice the same sale-code calling home too often, send the customer an updated bill.
5. Forgo authentication communication entirely, and instead use a dongle.  A small USB stick with an installation of your software that will check to see if that precise stick is present is a good start, but you may be able to find a vendor who can do more for you.
6. As above with the dongle, but instead make it the whole installer.  Have your "download" website register the particular computer, and generate an installer that will work for that computer and only that computer.

Note that, no matter what you do, a determined individual will be able to use your software in violation of your terms of sale, and you will NOT be able to catch them all.

Comment: Thanks, DougM, that was very helpful. I think I will go the No. 2 way and just have a 1 time registration.

Comment: Do that but do understand it will take seconds before hackers release a modified version of your program that runs without keys.

Comment: The likely hack for a simple key-store in the registry is just distributing the key.  Hacking an EXE so it doesn't perform the same check is, quite likely, less work than replicating the calculator.  (Assuming that it's not an interpreted language app.)